# Responsive bootstrap span floating off row-fluid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html

I have several layouts made with responsive bootstrap rows, but when my window is resized to a certain width, all the blocks (either `span6` or `span4`) fall out of the row, as if they were overflowing. I would understand an overflow happening with `span6`'s, since their widths are complementary, but `span4`'s? Why are they all forming into a single column?

If i shrink my window further, the blocks return to their rightful place, which is telling me it is not a question of non-fitting div widths. I included some screenshots to illustrate what i'm saying.

### Full size

[image: Full size]

### Cells flowing off

[image: Cells flowing off]

### Smaller width, cells returned

[image: Smaller width, cells returned]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The css for the responsive bootstrap had a hole in the width adjustment, so in the span between 1200px width and 970-something the `span` div lost its `float: left` property

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is **dont use row-fluid** because if you want to fix the layout of `.spanX` then you have to customize the css of the bootstrap, try use **twitter bootstrap tables** for this, it will be perfect for you... Thanks...